# Finding the minimum spanning tree of a graph using Kruskal's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, kruskals-algorithm, prims-algorithm

[Here is a Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ny6n.png) where I need to find the minimum spanning tree of G using **Prim's** and **Kruskal's** algorithms.

I found the minimum spanning tree using Prim's algorithm. [Here is my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYgw3.png).

I am having difficulty in finding the minimum spanning tree using Kruskal's algorithm. I have seen many videos related to Kruskal's graph algorithm but I ended up getting the same graph as Prim's algorithm.

Can anyone please show me how to find the minimum spanning tree of the graph using Kruskal's algorithm?

Comment: Why do you think they should produce different results?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Because, these are two different algorithms

Comment: Looks like all the edges in the graph have distinct weights.  That means that there is only *one* minimum spanning tree.  Any algorithm you use to find it should find the same one.

Comment: @MattTimmermans So, by using either Prim's or Kruskal's algorithm, do we get the same result for this graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prims and Kruskals will always give you the same answer if all the
>   edges of the graph have distinct weights, as there is only a single min-spanning tree that exists. For graph having many edges with
>   same weights, the algorithms **could** give you a different answer but not
>   always. Depends on the way the nodes are explored in the
>   implementation. This graph can have many different min-spanning trees.

As your graph has all distinct edge weights, you will always get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Prim's and Kruskal's algorithm both find minimum spanning trees. Because the graph that you gave has edge weights that are all different from each other there will be no different spanning trees that are both minimum.as long as both algorithms are correctly implemented they will find the same tree. meaning there can be no variation between the MST.