# Maximise number of edges to cut in connected graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, undirected-graph, tarjans-algorithm

This question is very similar to [Leetcode's Critical Connections in a Network](https://leetcode.com/problems/critical-connections-in-a-network/). Given an undirected graph, we want to find all bridges. An edge in an undirected connected graph is a *bridge* iff removing it disconnects the graph.

**Variant**

Instead of finding all bridges, I want to **maximise** the number of edges to remove so that the graph remains connected.

**Example 1**

`Input: n = 5, edges = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [3, 4], [1, 4], [4, 5]]`
[image]

`Output: 1`

Firstly, I can remove `[3,4]`, `[1,3]`, or `[1,4]`. Next, after removing either of the 3 edges, the remaining edges are all bridges. Hence, the maximum number of edges to remove so that the graph remains connected is 1.

**Example 2**

`Input: n = 6, edges = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]`
[image]

`Output: 2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the minimum spanning tree of a graph using Kruskal's Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210491/finding-the-minimum-spanning-tree-of-a-graph-using-kruskals-algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is easy, if we have `E` edges and `N` nodes in a connected graph we can remove `E-N+1` edges so that graph remains connected.

How to do this?:

Just do DFS/BFS to find any spanning tree of the graph, since spanning tree is connected we can just remove all other edges.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Note that if you just want the output to be the *number* of edges to remove, then you don't need to construct the spanning tree; `E - N + 1` is the answer, always.